# Ruby on Rails || Following conferences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

I'm trying to create an app in Ruby on Rails where I can:

- Create conferences (working)
- See a listing of conferences (working)
- Follow and unfollow a conference (not working)
- View a following conference (not working)

I've started working with Ruby on Rails back in December and used Micheal Hartl's tutorial to get started. In chapter 14 (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users) Micheal introduces following and unfollowing users, trough relationships.

I'm trying to apply his techniques, but adjusting it to where you have a relation between one model and one controller, to where there are two models and two controllers.

One controller & model is the User_controller and the User Model, the other controller & model are the Conference_controller and the Conference Model.

I started by adding active relations to the User Model, since it's the party that's following the conferences

**user.rb**

```
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
```

I've done the opposite in the Conference Model, because i'ts the party thats being followed

**Conference.rb**

```
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

To make the structure cleared I've added to following line of code to the Relationship model

**Relationship.rb**

```
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "Conference"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
```

When trying to see if the user is actually following the conference an error occurs in the User model stating:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in RelationshipsController#create

SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: relationships.follower_id, relationships.followed_id: INSERT INTO "relationships" ("follower_id", "followed_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The root of the problem lies in:

```
app/models/user.rb:116:in `follow'
app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

I understand that the problem occurs when a record cannot be inserted because it would violate a uniqueness constraint, but I don't know what uniqueness constraint is being violated.

Now the first problem happens in the **user.rb**, when an active_relationship is being created between user and conference.

```
  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_conference)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

  # Follows a conference.
  def follow(other_conference)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_conference.id)
  end

  # Unfollows a conference.
  def unfollow(other_conference)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_conference.id).destroy
  end
```

The second problem is in the Relationships_controller, where the current_user should follow the conference.

```
def create
    @conference = Conference.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@conference)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @conference }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Now i'm not sure what the cause of the problem is and how to solve it. I hope I've made my problem clear and what i'm trying to achieve. If not I would gladly give more information concerning my problem.

Comment: `has_many :followings` - pay careful attention to pluralization when creating associations and naming things in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're following an example that handles a more complex case (where you're joining the same table twice) and your solution is a bit more complicated than it needs to be:

```
class User
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :conferances, though: :subscriptions

  def subscribed_to?(conference)
    conferances.include?(conference)
  end

  def find_subscription(conference)
    subscriptions.find_by(conference: conference)
  end
end

class Conferance
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, though: :subscriptions
end

# Its better to name join models after an actual thing
class Subscription
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conference
end
```

---

```
resources :conferences, shallow: true do
  resource :subscriptions, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

---

```
class SubscriptionsController
  before_action :set_conferance, only: :create

  def create
    if current_user.subsciptions.create(conferance: @conferance)
      flash[:success] = "You are now subscribed to { @conferance.name }"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not create subscription."
    end
    redirect_to @conferance
  end

  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subsciptions.find(params[:id])
    if @subscription.destroy
      flash[:success] = "You are no longer subscribed to { @conferance.name }"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Oh noes"
    end

    redirect_to @subscription.conferance 
  end

  def set_conferance
    @conferance = Conferance.find(params[:conferance_id])
  end
end
```

---

```
<% if current_user.subscribed_to?(@conferance) %>
  <%= button_to "Subscribe", conferance_subsciptions_path(@conferance), method: :post %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Unsubscribe", subscription_path(current_user.find_subscription(@conferance)), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I used Subscription instead since bending follow into a noun and various forms is so awkward.

Comment: Thank you Max, this has helped me solve my problem! I wish I had a way to repay you!

Comment: Max, I'm running into a problem with the def set_conferance, where i'm getting the error message undefined local variable or method `conference_id'

Comment: nvm, got it! @conference = Conference.find_by id: params["conference_id"] :)

Comment: Oops, happy you caught my typo.

Comment: I'm really great-full for your help :)